# Determining all points where 2 mod patterns converge

Tags: c#, python, mathematical-optimization

This may be more of a math question, but I am trying to do this in Python and/or C#/Java(script) in the most efficient way possible

There exists a single data series from 1 to n which increments by 1:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10......n
```

there also exists two integer variables:  x and y

For each value in the data series, a value for n % x and  n % y  is calculated

For example:

```
let x = 1,  y = 3

n           n % x       n % y
----        -----       -----
1             0           1
2             0           2
3             0           0
4             0           1
5             0           2
6             0           0
...
```

Problem:  return a list of values of data the series `n` that would return a zero value for both `n % x` and `n % y`

In the above example, the list would be [1,6,9,12...etc]

Comment: 3 belongs in the output, and 1 doesn't.

Comment: search for "least common multiple"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference code like this.

```
def function(n, x, y):
    result_list = [1]
    for i_n in range(1, n):
        if ((i_n % x) == 0) and ((i_n % y) == 0):
            result_list.append(i_n)
    return result_list

print(function(50, 1, 3))
```

At the code, use the `n` to `50` for example, you can change for you need.

The code output is，

```
[1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48]
```

Comment: ok I was hoping there was some magical math equation to do this so I wouldn't have to use a loop (this is for a high speed application) but this solution works well.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of the code, I'll have a hard time giving you the solution, so here's the universal answer:

At the beginning of the program, you create an empty list with `zeros = []`. After that, in each step of the loop where you let `n` increase, you check if `n % x == 0 And n % y == 0`. If it returns `True`, you add the current `n` to the list with `zeros.append(n)`